# How to override AddressImpl in Broadleaf

Tags: hibernate, broadleaf-commerce

I need to remove the `nullable="false"` constraint from the `POSTAL_CODE` field in [org.broadleafcommerce.profile.core.domain.AddressImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.broadleafcommerce/broadleaf-profile/2.0.0-GA/org/broadleafcommerce/profile/core/domain/AddressImpl.java). I tried creating an orm.xml with:

```
<entity class="org.broadleafcommerce.profile.core.domain.AddressImpl">
      <attribute-override name="postalCode">
        <column name="POSTAL_CODE" nullable="true" />
    </attribute-override>
</entity>
```

No luck... I'm trying hard not to create a brand new `BLC_ADDRESS` table because that just seems redundant... How can I override this column and remove that constraint?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue after many tries:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <entity 
        name="AddressImpl"
        class="org.broadleafcommerce.profile.core.domain.AddressImpl"
        access="FIELD"
        metadata-complete="false">

        <!-- POSTAL_CODE should accept null values -->
        <attribute-override name="postalCode">
            <column name="POSTAL_CODE" nullable="true"/>
        </attribute-override>

    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```